# Titanium webview local html Ti is not defined

Tags: android, webview, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

Hello does anyone know how to fix this issue in titanium webview using loacal html file??

**Ti is not defined**

In my **local html** file i have

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent('app:fromWebView',{ message: 'hi' });"/>
```

In my titanium **app file** i have below code

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('app:fromWebView', function(d) {

if(d.message== 'hi'){

alert('hi');

};

});
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?..

i'm using titanium **sdk 3.4.0**

Answer (score 1):

Should be working like that, maby comment out all other code and try this basic example (https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Communication+Between+WebViews+and+Titanium):

index.js:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
  var webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
  url: 'test.html'
});


Ti.App.addEventListener('app:fromWebView', function(e) {
  alert(e.message);
});

win.add(webview);
win.open();
```

test.html:

```
<html>
<body onload="Ti.API.info('body loaded!');">        
    <button onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent('app:fromWebView', { message: 'event fired from WebView, handled in Titanium' });">fromWebView</button>
</body>
</html>
```